# Get Current component state and store it in redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

How to get latest updated react component state (after all the state changes are done) and put the same object in Redux.

Get the latest state and dispatch an action (with a copy of current state) only once instead of dispatching the same action from different methods where state is getting altered ?

Is there any efficient way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

First If your state doesn't need multiple pages then no need to store the state in the redux, use local state.

But if you want to use redux and want latest state, then if you want this state in the stateless component(functional) then you can use **useSelector** redux hook for the latest data, and if you want the state in the stateful component then use **mapStateToProps**.

useful links:
for hooks: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector

for mapStateToProps: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#defining-mapstatetoprops

Comment: For more clarity, let me explain the usecase: I have a component and want to store it's state by dispatching an action with current state object (a copy of this.state) as payload. I do not want to dispatch this action from every method which is altering current state. So, can I use any component lifecycle method or Is there any other right place to dispatch an action with this.state only once?